# Xcode complains link error: "Undefine symbol: '_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKAdImpression'" after pod GoogleMobileAdsMediationAdColony

Tags: swift, xcode, admob, adcolony

I'm trying to add AdColony mediation into AdMob.
I follow the instructions from 'https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/mediation/adcolony'.

After pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationAdColony', I open Xcode to test my app and get a link error:

`Undefine symbol: '_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKAdImpression'`

as well as a warning:

`Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'AVFAudio'`

I googled but got nothing.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi there, were you able to resolve the issue? I have the same one..

Comment: hi @NebihBaşaran! Not yet.

Comment: updating xCode version to 12.5 resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SKAdImpression](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skadimpression) looks like a class that is new to iOS 14.5  so you likely need Xcode 12.5+ to contain that class definition.

I was running into the same Undefined symbol: '*OBJC_CLASS*$_SKAdImpression' error under Xcode 12.4, but upgrading to 12.5 fixed for me.

Comment: Although I could not find the download link for xcode 12.5 yet, I believe this is the answer, thank you! @mackelrow

Answer (score 3):

Version 4.6.1 of the iOS AdColony SDK requires Xcode 12.5.

From [the changelog](https://github.com/AdColony/AdColony-iOS-SDK/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md):

> 4.6.1 (2021/04/21)
>
> - SKAdNetwork view-through attribution support
> - ***Build requires Xcode 12.5***

This does mean that if you go back to 4.6.0 you should *not* need Xcode 12.5. You can do this by selecting a specific version of the 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationAdColony' pod:

```
pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationAdColony', '4.6.0.0'
```

You can see in the [podspec here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/a/9/2/GoogleMobileAdsMediationAdColony/4.6.0.0/GoogleMobileAdsMediationAdColony.podspec.json) that this version uses version 4.6.0 of the AdColony SDK.

Obviously this is not a long-term solution, but as Xcode 12.5 requires Big Sur it allows a little more time before having to run an major OS update all your dev machines.